# Serving GeoTIFFs of different resolutions as single layer

Tags: geoserver, gdal, gdal-merge

I'm trying to serve a 30 arc second DEM with global coverage combined with high resolution 1/3 arc second DEM for a very small area.

- I believed at first I could combine them into a single file, however this seems impossible as the file would end up as around 45GB

Questions

- Is there another way of solving this problem using geoserver?
- Alternative formats which support this?
- Can the Image Mosaic plugin in Geoserver deal with this? I've tried, but it doesn't appear to work. The documentation implies only a single resolution can be dealt with, however the Heterogeneous=true option implies multiple resolutions?

Details of the two files

```
gdalinfo GEBCO_2014_1D_EPSG4326.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: GEBCO_2014_1D_EPSG4326.tif
Size is 43200, 21600
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.008333333333333,-0.008333333333333)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Band 1 Block=43200x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray

gdalinfo asc/puerto-rico.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: asc/puerto-rico.tif
Size is 24301, 11881
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-67.600046296295005,18.800046283695000)
Pixel Size = (0.000092592590000,-0.000092592590000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -67.6000463,  18.8000463) ( 67d36' 0.17"W, 18d48' 0.17"N)
Lower Left  ( -67.6000463,  17.6999537) ( 67d36' 0.17"W, 17d41'59.83"N)
Upper Right ( -65.3499538,  18.8000463) ( 65d20'59.83"W, 18d48' 0.17"N)
Lower Right ( -65.3499538,  17.6999537) ( 65d20'59.83"W, 17d41'59.83"N)
Center      ( -66.4750000,  18.2500000) ( 66d28'30.00"W, 18d15' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=24301x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Comment: Pixels in all image formats that I know have a fixed size. If you want to merge your 1/3 arc second file into the 30 arc second file with full resolution you must resample the latter also with 1/3 arc second pixels which makes the file 90 times bigger and probably does not make sense. I would keep the both images as they are and draw the high resolution image over the low resolution one.

Comment: I believe JPEG2000 supports variable resolution, but I'm not sure that many applications will make use of it. What is the end goal of this coverage (DEM)?

Comment: Thanks, at least I know it's not possible now using a single file. I'm now trying to get geoserver mosaic plugin to do this, but struggling, it doesn't seem to provide the extra detail when zoomed in over the hi-res area...

Comment: GeoServer ImageMosaic goes well with multiple resolution (lateral) Did you try Sorting="resolution D", so that the high resolution stays on top?